# Своя картинка в JQ cropit

Tags: jquery

Доброго

есть такая штука - [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) (первый пример, с корабликом). Вроде все так наглядно, с кодом и примерчиками, но есть заковырка. Если ставить себе то ест-но картинку хочется свою, а не выбирать каждый раз. Ест-но примера использования кода нету. Может ли кто такой привести? Или аналогичную штуковину с зумом? ( эта понравилась из за регулятора зума )

p.s. да, прописывать путь до нужной картинки уже пробовал, но результата два, или пример не работает, или грузит демонстрационные картинки из инета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации

```
// Sets image source.
$imageCropper.cropit('imageSrc', 'http://placekitten.com/g/1280/800');
```